# Position and size of window whith Desktop Java class

Tags: java, desktop

The following code opens a text file with the application that the operating system has set.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    try {
      Desktop desktop = null;
      if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
      }

       desktop.open(new File("c:\\a.txt"));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

From here, I can know the size and position of the window that opens?

Thanks for the help.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a simple way.  The method doesn't return anything and window that opens will be a completely separate application anyway.

There might be a way that would be OS specific to look at running processes and build something to collect this information but it would not be easy.

Comment: Do you know any way to know the position (and size) of windows, external applications like Notepad + +, which are opened from a Java program?

Answer (score 0):

If you wnat to use the Java Toolkit class, so the following Java code demonstrates how to get the screen size:

```
// screen size with Dimension Class
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
```

After you get the screen size as a Dimension object,
you can get the height and width as follows:

```
// screen height
screenSize.getHeight();

// screen width
screenSize.getWidth();
```