# java Desktop Browser popup window

Tags: java, browser, desktop

I use the below code to launch a web page in default system browser:

```
String url = "http://www.google.com"; 

java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
```

however i want my web page to be displayed in a popup browser window with a given size (with,height) like we can do in javascript with Window Object.

is there a way i can control from java the default browser and ask it to open a popup window with a given size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position and size of window whith Desktop Java class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334999/position-and-size-of-window-whith-desktop-java-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is this good project http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/

you invoke a new browser window like below. however it probably doesn't offer option for setting window height and width.

```
BrowserLauncher browser =new BrowserLauncher();
                browser.setNewWindowPolicy(true);
                browser.openURLinBrowser(url);
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways I can think of to approach this problem:

1. Instead of going directly to the target URL, open an intermediate URL like http://our.com/bouce.html?url=google.com&w=400&h=300  Then bounce.html uses JavaScript to open url @ w X h.
2. Use a `JEditorPane`.  The much maligned editor pane is not ideal for real world browsing, but can deal with a variety of sites, and it is improving with each release (most of the time, anyway).

Comment: I don't think JEditorpane is powerfull enough for my needs. I tried some embedded browsers like SWT but i'm facing problems with SWT on linux and as you know SWT is not platform independent. i also tried lobo swing browser but it fails to work for me. It becomes very frastrating for me that i opted to use default system browser; but i yet want to open a browser popup window for better user experience of my application.

Comment: *"I don't think JEditorpane is powerfull enough for my needs."*  Stop thinking and **test**. *"but i yet want to open a browser popup window"* So use technique 1.

Comment: And do I have to play "20 questions" about why you do not use technique 1?  I'm not that interested in playing games.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in pure Java.

If you really need to do this, you will need some way to find out what the user's default browser is.  Then launch you will need to launch a browser instance using `System.exec`, supplying the appropriate command line arguments.

Comment: there is an old version of a java class called BareBonesBrowser which tries to detect what browser a user uses and lauch it with a system command line. do you know of any java class on the web that does this ?